# How to get the latest records in hive using rank function

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop

I have below table in hive with column id, name and time stamp:

[image: table]

On the basis of time stamp below should be the output as latest record:

[image: table]

Comment: Gordon is right. You only need rank or row_number if you wanted let's say to get the lastest for each id

Answer (score 3):

You don't need rank for this.  Your output is described by:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.transaction_time desc
limit 3;
```

EDIT:

Oh, you want `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by t.transaction_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query but how can i apply limit 3? because i don`t know how many records entered on that particular of time. It may be 3 or 30 records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `rank` or `row_number` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by name 
            order by transaction_time desc
            ) as seq
    from your_table t
    ) t 
where seq = 1;
```