# Isolating MySql records created today

Tags: mysql

I am just learning MySql (SQL in general) and I have a question. I ran a process to populate a table with 72 records. This was done, however, I needed to run the process again and this time it populated the table again with a second record for each user for a total now of 144 records. How can I isolate the newest records created today?

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Do you store a timestamp of some sort?

Comment: There is a createdTS and UpdatedTS.

Comment: update your question add  the table schema   and a data sample

Comment: 'newest records created today' - from what timepoint today (or other criterion)?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use your `createdTS` column, (assuming you know what was the timestamp of both runs).

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `createdTS` > '2019-07-25 15:00:00'
```

You could also `RANK()` over and get only the newest run for each user (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306812/2992745))

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use [current_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) to figure out today's date and [date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to remove the time portion of your column. Then:

```
where current_date = date(createdTS)
```

This is fine for a small dataset as yours. As general solution, you'd need a query that won't need to manipulate every row, e.g.

```
where createdTS >= current_date and createdTS < current_date + interval 1 day
```